# Strip Whitenoise from Audio File using Modern Javascript in the Browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-audio-api

I would like to record audio, and once the recording has finished, automatically trim whitenoise (no sound) from the beginning and end of the recorded audio file.

The solution's do not need to support older browsers. (i.e. IE11) and I would perfectly happy with anything that worked in the latest version of google chrome.

I've been taking a long look at WebAudio and looking through the online book http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001552/ch01.html#s01_2 but I have been unable to work out how to get this trimming to work.

So far i've got recording working with the MediaRecorder API which outputs into an array of blobs.

I've also found:
https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html which uses the web-audio-api directly to do a live stream of the data.

Comment: I've got a working solution to this.  I'll update after cleaning the code.

Comment: So how you do it?